# how to specify endpoint address for WCF service hosted on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have simple wcf service with basicHttpBindings and want to host it on IIS.

but when I'm specifying 
`<endpoint address="/myAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf.Contracts.IPublicService"/>`
 myAddress is ignored. In other words I'm expecting it creates my service endpoint sth like this localhost:1111/myaddress/PublicService.svc, but it creates endpoint simply by combining localhost and PublicService.svc - localhost:1111/publicservice.svc.

why I need?
I have some other services hosted in project and want to create each of them with different url after localhost.(I don't want to move them to different folder).

**I've googled and discovered that host base address is ignored when hosting on IIS, is this true for endpoint addresse too?**

thanks in advance

```
<service name="Wcf.Services.AdminService">
    <endpoint address="/address" binding ="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf.Contracts.IAdminService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding ="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <service name="Wcf.Services.PublicService">
    <endpoint address="/address1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Wcf.Contracts.IPublicService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

Comment: If you put your service in a folder called "myAddress", the path will change from /PublicService.svc -> /myAddress/PublicService.svc.  If you want to store them all in one place but to different paths, you should look at adding ServiceRoutes.

Comment: but why we need endpoint address if it cannot be used "appropriately"? Are they only for self hosted services in windows service?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the base address of your service is `http://localhost:1111/PublicService.svc`, specifying the `address="/myAddress"` attribute would cause that endpoint’s address to become `http://localhost:1111/PublicService.svc/myAddress`. The endpoint’s relative path comes *after* the service address.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might be something like in the Service.svc file...

Open it and modify the single line in it like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Wcf.Services.PublicService" %>
```

You can follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/05/21/hosting-wcf-service-in-iis.aspx) good tutorial, I just did it a few days ago...

Hope it helps!